# Office 2013 theme in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ms-office

I am looking to create a presentation for my work using the ReporteRs package. It all works fine but I need a way to print Office 2013 like graphs ( I know they look worse but thats where I am stuck at ) using ggplot. Is there a theme which can implement the same?

I did look into the package 'ggthemes' and the theme_excel() but that does not give the required output. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards
Nishant

Comment: You could create your own theme. Please show an example graph in your question as many of us don't have access to Office 2013.

Comment: Copy https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/blob/master/R/excel.R and map the colors and borders (etc). Should not take long if you have Excel 2013 handy (I do not).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Sorry for not reverting back earlier. The excel theme was a real help.